# EFCore transaction rollback behavior if process is killed

Tags: sql-server, transactions, ef-core-2.0

Currently I have a base class for integration tests using NUnit on a .net Core 2 project (EFCore 2.01).  In this project we create a transaction on setup and do a rollback on tear down to isolate the tests.

```
public class BaseTestsWithRollbackPerTest : BaseTests
{
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        this.Transaction = this.ApplicationContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        this.Transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

One of my colleges brought up a concern that we may have lingering transactions if someone may to abort a test or shut off their PC/VS2017 hangs etc.

I have checked and the database and XACT_Abort is switched off and this is a long existing database so I may not be able to change that setting.

My question is what is the standard process for EFCore with this? Will it abort the transaction or keep it going?  Are there any settings that I have not been able to find?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not different than in ADO.NET

Comment: @IvanStoev cool expanding my google search now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a transaction is never committed, it will timeout and the SQLServer will perform a rollback. The SQLServer will handle this, not EF.